# VBA Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I need to simply count the number of areas on a sheet.  The code I have is :

```
Sub areas()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Worksheets("Sheet2").Selection.Areas.Count
   MsgBox i
End Sub
```

But for some reason I get the error message "Object doesn't support this property or method." I have no idea why. This code was basically just copied from the Microsoft website.

I can't even get the immediate window to print the `Worksheets("Sheet2").Selection.Areas.Count` portion.

Any quick help? I am using Excel 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: from where did you copy that?

Comment: The MSDN dev center gives the example of "Selection.Areas.Count"  So all I did was add the "Worksheets..." portion.

Comment: so I can't add in a reference to a specific sheet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Think of it like if anything after the dot is called on an object. It's like a chain.

An object is a class instance. A class instance supports some properties defined in that class type definition. It exposes whatever intelli-sense in VBE tells you (*there are some hidden members but it's not related to this*). So after each dot `.` you get intelli-sense (*that white dropdown*) trying to help you pick the correct **action**.

(*you can start either way - front to back or back to front*, once you understand how this works you'll be able to identify where the problem occurs)

Type this much anywhere in your code area

```
Dim a As Worksheets
a.
```

you get help from VBE, it's a little dropdown called Intelli-sense

[image]

It lists all available **actions** that particular object exposes to any user. You can't see the `.Selection` member of the `Worksheets()` class. That's what the error tells you exactly.

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

If you look at [the example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838793.aspx)

```
Worksheets("GRA").Activate
iAreaCount = Selection.Areas.Count
```

It `activates` the sheet first then calls the `Selection...` it's not connected together because `Selection` is not a member of `Worksheets()` class. Simply, you can't **prefix** the `Selection`

What about

```
Sub DisplayColumnCount()
    Dim iAreaCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Worksheets("GRA").Activate
    iAreaCount = Selection.Areas.Count

    If iAreaCount <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Columns.Count & " columns."
    Else
        For i = 1 To iAreaCount
        MsgBox "Area " & i & " of the selection contains " & _
        Selection.Areas(i).Columns.Count & " columns."
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

from [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838793.aspx)

Comment: so I can't use a range reference that is not "Selection"?

Comment: Of course you can. But you need an [instance of `Range` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx).