# Excel VBA error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

Ok so I'm definitely a novice at VBA but I'm learning. As far as I can tell there no reason my code shouldn't be running fine, and has in the past. This error keeps popping up though. What the intention is I'm making a sheet that automatically updates the other sheets when you add a person to the main sheet. The code seems to work and has, but it is suddenly throwing this error and I can't figure out why. I've looked around but none of the solutions seem to be remotely relevant to my issue. Any help at figuring out exactly where the error is would be greatly appreciated!

The following is where the debugger is saying the error is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateSheets (Week2)
End sub
```

And this is the function being called:

```
Public Function UpdateSheets(ByRef w As Worksheet)
HowManyPeople
With w
    .Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 1 To x
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            For j = 2 To 12
                .Cells(i + 4, j).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                If j <> 12 Then
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Locked = False
                Else
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Locked = True
                End If
                If j = 2 Then
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Value = Week1.Cells(i + 4, j)
                Else
                    .Cells(i + 4, j).Value = "0"
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    i = x + 5
    Do
        For j = 2 To 12
            .Cells(i, j).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
            .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Cells(i, j).Locked = True
            .Cells(i, j).Value = ""
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j))
End With

End Function
```

the function HowManyPeople is a basic row counting method. x is a public workbook variable given value in the HowManyPeople method. Week1 and Week2 are the technical names (not displayed name) of the worksheets

Comment: Please replace `ThisWorkbook.UpdateSheets (Week2)`  with `ThisWorkbook.UpdateSheets Week2` and make sure UpdateSheets is located in ThisWorkbook module. or simply use  `UpdateSheets Week2`

Comment: If you do an Insert->Module in VBA, and put your UpdateSheets(...) into the Module, then you do not need the "ThisWorkbook." prefix on the function call, and you can call it from any worksheet.  You should also set a breakpoint inside your UpdateSheets and if it gets invoked, then step through it to find the real error line.  Sometimes the Excel debugger gets confused, and tags the line calling the function as the point of error, when the error is really inside the called function.

Comment: Can you show, how do you have the 'Week2` variable set up?

Comment: I'm having diffulcity understanding how your **Function** is able to change anything on a worksheet.  Functions can't change anything on a worksheet apart from the cell from which they are called. **Subs**  modify application, book, sheet and range properties; **Functions** return Objects or values,

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald That is not precisely correct.  Functions (and called child Functions and child Subs) are only blocked from changing Excel cells if the top-level function was invoked by an Excel cell formula.  Subs plus any *called Functions* and called Subs CAN change Excel cells if the top-level sub was invoked from say a UI control or an Excel event or the Macros button on the Developer ribbon.  I change Excel cells in all sorts of functions (the function return in those cases are success/fail codes).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

In the sub, change this :
`ThisWorkbook.UpdateSheets (Week2)`
to this
`Call UpdateSheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week2"))`

### Explanation of the problem

See [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21557753/4636801)
There is no `UpdateSheets` member of `ThisWorkbook` object.