# Microsoft Excel VBA - Run-Time Error 438

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I appear to be having an error which I am struggling to figure out the reason. I have tried the help sections and also tried researching it online but have not come up with any results. I am hoping someone may be able to assist me in the matter.

**Issue**

I have created multiple forms for different sheets on my spreadsheet. I have made forms which can be used to hide/show select column(s) by user discretion. I have two forms which work perfectly fine, but on the third.

I get

> Run-Time Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

What does this mean? The code is the exact same as the other forms. The only difference in them is that the names of the sheets are different.

I will paste the code below for the sheets. Hopefully you can distinguish which is which. I will try and do my best to explain.

**Code below**

***Main sheet - contains button to form open form***

```
Private Sub openUserForm_Click()
    chkFormCooms.Show
End Sub
```

**Userform**

```
Option Explicit

Sub hideCol(C As Integer)
    If Controls("CheckBox" & C) = True Then
        Columns(C).Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns(C).Hidden = False
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub

Private Sub chkP1_Click()
    If Me.chkP1.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("T:W").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk1.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP1.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("T:W").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP2_Click()
    If Me.chkP2.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("X:AA").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk2.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP2.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("X:AA").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk2.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP3_Click()
   If Me.chkP3.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AB:AE").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk3.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP3.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AB:AE").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk3.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP4_Click()
    If Me.chkP4.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AF:AI").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk4.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP4.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AF:AI").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk4.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP5_Click()
   If Me.chkP5.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AJ:AM").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk5.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP5.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AJ:AM").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk5.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP6_Click()
    If Me.chkP6.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AN:AQ").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk6.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP6.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AN:AQ").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk6.Value = False
    End If
 End Sub

Private Sub chkP7_Click()
    If Me.chkP7.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AR:AU").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk7.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP7.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AR:AU").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk7.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP8_Click()
    If Me.chkP8.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Coomst").Columns("AV:AY").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk8.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP8.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AV:AY").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk8.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkP9_Click()
    If Me.chkP9.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AZ:BC").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk9.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP9.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AZ:BC").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk9.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub chkP10_Click()
    If Me.chkP10.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BD:BG").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk10.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP10.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BD:BG").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk10.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub chkP11_Click()
    If Me.chkP11.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BH:BK").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk11.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP11.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BH:BK").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk11.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub chkP12_Click()
    If Me.chkP12.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BL:BO").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk12.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP12.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BL:BO").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk12.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub chkP13_Click()
    If Me.chkP13.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BP:BS").Hidden = True
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk13.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.chkP13.Value = False Then
        Sheets("Cooms").Columns("BP:BS").Hidden = False
        Sheets("chkCooms").chk13.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.chkP1.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk1.Value
    Me.chkP2.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk2.Value
    Me.chkP3.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk3.Value
    Me.chkP4.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk4.Value
    Me.chkP5.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk5.Value
    Me.chkP6.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk6.Value
    Me.chkP7.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk7.Value
    Me.chkP8.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk8.Value
    Me.chkP9.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk9.Value
    Me.chkP10.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk10.Value
    Me.chkP11.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk11.Value
    Me.chkP12.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk12.Value
    Me.chkP13.Value = Sheets("chkCooms").chk13.Value
End Sub
```

I hope this all makes sense and that someone is able to assist me in this matter. If you need further explanation then please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: In which code line do you get the error?

Comment: Unrelated, but your code's a lot more verbose than it needs to be. Those `If` statements which assign `True` or `False` to something could be refactored as (for example) `Sheets("Cooms").Columns("AF:AI").Hidden = Me.chkP4.Value`. Also, it looks like you're doing the same thing for 13 different check boxes, so you could consider writing a single parameterised function.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Apologies for not stating the line. I get the error in the Main Sheet code.

Comment: @jsheeran Thank you for informing me of this. I'm very new to VBA and am still learning how to make the code a lot more simpler and cleaner. I shall keep this in mind for the furture. :)

Comment: You mean you get the error on `chkFormCooms.Show`? Then please set the cursor here and go through it step-by-step (with F8) to see where the error actually is. It is probably in the `UserForm_Initialize` and probably one of these `chkP1…13` or `chk1…13` do not exist.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is correct.  After you get your code running you should post it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  The experts there will give you some great advice on how to structure your code better.

Comment: What is `Sheets("chkCooms").chk1` and the others?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thankfully you were correct. I went through it step-by-step which I did not realise I could do. I sourced the error out. Thank you for your information. It helped a lot :)

Answer (score -4):

Check the name of your userform its probably spelt incorrectly

For information about the error check this [amazing description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557683/vba-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)