# Excel VBA to trigger events in web page once input box get filled with data

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to fill one input box in web page which actually trigger events results in auto update some hidden fields.

code behind web page

```
<INPUT onchange=iCFieldChanged(this); tabIndex=1017 onkeypress="AllowOnly(event, '[()0-9-+]','');" onfocus="tbInitialValue=this.value;g_fFieldValue = this.value;g_fFieldId = this.id;" onblur="if(tbInitialValue!=this.value &amp;&amp; Page_IsValid){executingPostBack=true;__doPostBack('dnn:ctr366:ClaimPhysicianInformation:_ctl2:Datapanel:_ctl0:_ctl5:ClaimRecipient:ds_ClaimRecipient:mb_ds_ClaimRecipient', '');}g_fFieldId = null;" id=dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient onpaste="return true;" style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" maxLength=10 size=11 value=9468381692 name=dnn:ctr366:ClaimPhysicianInformation:_ctl2:Datapanel:_ctl0:_ctl5:ClaimRecipient:ds_ClaimRecipient:mb_ds_ClaimRecipient>
```

There are 5 event listeners on the first input tag line of the code above - `onblur`,`onkeypress`,`onfocus`,`onchange`,`onpaste`. I can able to pass value to the input box but associated events not get released.

code tried (no errors but events not dispatched)

```
ie.Document.getElementById("dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient").Value = memberId
'tried with all fire event combinations but nothing works
ie.Document.getElementById("dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient").FireEvent ("onkeypress")
```

also tried to dispatch events but its showing error

```
Set srchbtn = ie.Document.getElementById("dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient")
    srchbtn.Value = memberId
    'getting error in next line
    Set event_onChange = ie.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "keypress", True, False
    srchbtn.dispatchEvent event_onChange
```

also tried keypress events like below

```
Set objEvent = IE.Document.createEvent("keyboardEvent")
objEvent.initEvent "keypress", True, False
IE.Document.getElementById("dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient")(0).dispatchEvent objEvent
```

but same error appears

> error: Run time error '438' : object doesn't support this property or method

since its an secured web page I cant share the url for reproducing the code please guide me on further proceedings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help others who are facing same issue

```
  set srchbtn = ie.Document.getElementById("dnn_ctr366_ClaimPhysicianInformation__ctl2_Datapanel__ctl0__ctl5_ClaimRecipient_ds_ClaimRecipient_mb_ds_ClaimRecipient")
  srchbtn.Focus
  srchbtn.Value = memberId
  srchbtn.Blur
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your event of input can be fired correctly in IE without VBA? I tried to dispatch the `onchange` event and it worked. I followed the way in [this article](https://codedocu.com/office-365/Access/Controls/web-Browser/Vba,-HTMLSelect_colon_-FireEvent-OnChange-or-DispatchEvent?1890). You could refer to my simple sample below:

Input box: `<input name="q" onchange="alert('aaa');"/>`

VBA code:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "http://somewebsite"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ieA.Document
    Set Search = doc.getElementsByName("q")(0)   
    Search.Value = "VBA"

    Dim event_onChange As Object
    Set event_onChange = ieA.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    Search.dispatchEvent event_onChange

    ieA.Quit
    Set ieA = Nothing
End Sub
```

The function above also worked with `keypress` event. About the error you got, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557683/vba-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method) for more information.

Comment: yes @Yu Zhou event of input can be fired correctly in IE without VBA, and the provided reference will not help to proceed further