# InvalidSelector Error: compound class names not permitted using "FindElementByClass"

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classname, invalidselectorexception

I am having trouble with code while trying to take the class name. I have tried and run time error 32 is appearing as:

```
InvalidSelector Error: compund class names not permitted
```

Maybe somebody canhelp with the code below. I have chrome browser 103.5060.114 but web driver 103.5060.56 . I could not find other driver to wnload.

HTML:

```
<span dir="auto" title="Customer" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">Customer</span>
```

VBA code:

```
Sub iselementpresenttest()
    
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim ks As New Keys

'Init New Chrome instance & navigate to WebWhatsApp
bot.Start "chrome", "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
bot.Get "/"
bot.Window.Maximize
MsgBox "Please scan the QR code. After you are logged in, please confirm this message box by clicking 'ok'"
bot.Wait (3500)
        
'        If bot.FindElementByClass("_2qo4q _3NIfV") = 1 Then
'    Debug.Print "true"
'End If
        
        If bot.FindElementByClass("ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr") = 1 Then
'                If bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='pane-side']/div/div/div/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div/span") = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "true"
End If
'        If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[20]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span").Count > 0 Then
    If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[20]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span").Count > 0 Then
        bot.TakeScreenshot.ToExcel.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        
            bot.Quit
            MsgBox "Yes"
        Else
            bot.Quit
            MsgBox "NO"
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

My aim is to take the send receive whatsapp icon to the excel sheet

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I have added HTML code.

Comment: @Tim Williams, with FindByCssSelector could not find the object either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- The *classnames* of the `<span>` looks dynamic and and may change sooner or later, even may be next time you access the application afresh.
- Selenium doesn't permit [compund class names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536022/7429447)

---

### Solution

To identify the element you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("span[title='Customer']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@title='Customer' and text()='Customer']")
  ```

Comment: For first method FindElementByCss it writes Object does not support this method If bot.FindElementByCss("span[title='Customer']") = 1 Then

Comment: Second method is separate i guess. Both methods are given the same object does not support this method. Maybe you other way, how to take check mark read receipt from whatsapp via VBA to excel sheet?

Comment: _**Object does not support this method**_ isn't a Selenium error. Check [this](https://excelchamps.com/vba/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-438/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557683/vba-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method) discussion.

Comment: `bot.FindElementByCss()` or `bot.FindElementByXPath()` would always return the first matching element. So `If element = 1 Then` doesn't seems to be rational. Instead you can _`If bot.FindElementByCss("span[title='Customer']") Then`_

Comment: I want to write a for loop to find the customer first then go inside that div block and look for ElementByCss. But it gives me error when I this code. It writes element out of screenshot.        bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@data-testid='status-dblcheck']").TakeScreenshot.Copy
       Sheets(1).Cells(5, 5).Paste

Comment: Sounds to be a different question. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246500/discussion-between-xlmaster-and-undetected-selenium).

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.