VBA - Selenium GetElementByClass "Compound Class Names Not Permitted Error - Webdriver
I am new to using selenium, and while this is most likely a simple solution, I am having a difficult time finding documentation regarding selenium.
I am attempting to do is click a specific element on a webpage.  This is the native html code of which I am trying to manipulate

I was using this code
WDriver.GetElementByClass("material-symbols-rounded ml-2 icon-redirect").Click
and it is yielding an error of compound class names not permitted.  I tried removing the spaces from the string value, which yielded no elements found, as well as using "Set", which also yielded the same result.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008015/invalidselector-error-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-findelementbycl
